# SNOWFLAKE: Ambiguous columns error using variables & identifier() to define query columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is for a data analysis task, not ETL. I need to perform the same task over and over (at least 200x) in slightly different contexts, so I'm building my queries to run on variables for the column and table names. This allows me to update the column/table name once for each iteration of testing and run the multiple analysis queries easily.

This mostly works. For example:

```
SET ColName = 'MyColumnName';
SELECT identifier($ColName) FROM db.schema.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN db.schema.table2 t2 ON t1.JoinColumn = t2.JoinColumn
```

works if MyColumnName is in only table1 or table2, but throws the error **SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'MyColumnName'** when it is present in both tables. I would like to be able to  clear the ambiguity and do my comparison with something like:

```
SET ColName = 'MyColumnName';
SELECT t1.identifier($ColName), t2.identifier($ColName)
FROM db.schema.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN db.schema.table2 t2 
   ON t1.JoinColumn = t2.JoinColumn
```

I have not found a syntax variation that works for this. Most variations throw the error: "SQL compilation error: Unknown user-defined function T1.IDENTIFIER". Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you were after in that it's a little more convoluted but perhaps something like this:                                                                                                           SET ColNameT1 = 't1.MyColumnName';
SET ColNameT2 = 't2.MyColumnName';
SELECT identifier($ColNameT1), identifier($ColNameT2)
FROM db.schema.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN db.schema.table2 t2 
   ON t1.JoinColumn = t2.JoinColumn

Comment: In addition to Mike's suggestion above, you might want to explore UDTF's in Snowflake.  Perhaps you could use those to more dynamically build the SQL statement that is executed...and maybe have the column and table name be a parameter that you pass into it?  It would depend on how consistent the SQL form is, but that might be an idea.

Comment: @Mike Walton, if you mean passing column name as UDTF argument to the identifier(argument) function, it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I was suggesting creating a JS UDTF that builds the query dynamically based on the column name that you pass into the UDTF.  You wouldn't need an identifier function inside the UDTF in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve replacing 'ON' with 'USING' which puts them both in the same column in the output. With 'ON' it wants to create two columns, but can't because the name is the same.

```
SET ColName = 'MyColumnName';
SELECT t1.identifier($ColName), t2.identifier($ColName)
FROM db.schema.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN db.schema.table2 t2 
   USING(JoinColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using variables for tables as well:

```
SET ColName = 'MyColumnName';
SET t1 = 'db.schema.table1';
SET t2 = 'db.schema.table2';
SET t1ColName = $t1 || '.' || $ColName;
SET t2ColName = $t2 || '.' || $ColName;

SELECT identifier($t1ColName), identifier($t2ColName)
FROM  identifier($t1)
LEFT JOIN identifier($t2)
   ON identifier($t1).JoinColumn = identifier($t2).JoinColumn
```